# Field accessibility not deployed through change set

Tags: custom-field, change-set

While deploying through change set, I have added one custom field (checkbox) whose field accessibility has been changed. After deploying, the field accessibility has not been changed in the target organization. Please confirm what measures do I need to take for the same.

FYI- This custom field doesn't have any dependency on any other field nor does it has any validation rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other answers are correct in that you need to get the profile adjustments into your target org as well.

However, I have read in various places that it can sometimes be best NOT to deploy profiles along with the change-set to production... and that often its simpler to just make the necessary tweaks to profiles in production manually.

Part of the problem with deploying profiles is being sure that you're only changing those aspects that you want to change.

For example, in situations where you have multiple developers or teams sharing a sandbox environment, changes might have been made to profiles that you are not aware of, then those changes would get promoted along with your change, if you are not careful.

Answer (score 6):

You need to deploy Profile as well which you were changed the accessibility

Answer (score 6):

You will need to deploy the necessary profiles along with the fields to carry over the field accessibility .

Field Accessibility has dependency on the profiles and change sets by default does not include profiles as well

Comment: As a (lazy) rule, I generally include all profiles in all change sets with any new fields, objects etc. the change set only includes the ACTUAL bits of the profile needed/changed relevant to the other things in the set, so there is no massive overhead if they have no changes, but it stops me forgetting them, which can be a real pain if you have tonnes of new fields etc.!

Comment: @SimonLawrence Actually I believe system permissions come along for the ride, so there is some risk of override, but there are ways to mitigate that.

Comment: interesting, and thanks for the heads up. I might try to find some time to have a dig/go soon and see if I can cause myself trouble.